# Browser taking too long to recalculate style on an Angular application

Tags: html, css, angular, performance, inline-styles

I have an Angular 12 application that is like a calendar. It have multiple rows with multiple events inside each row, like on the image below. The green squares are the rows and the blue squares are the events.
[image: calendar illustration]
The left border is day 1, and the right border is day 8 in this scenario. So, if an event is on day 3 I have to place it inside its row accordingly. And I do it by calculating which day is on left border and which day is on right border, convert it into pixels and place it inside the row by css property. Blue squares have `position: absolute; left: 123px`. The left property value is controlled by angular and it is what puts it in place. Also, the rows can be dragged by a click and drag using mouse cursor, so the visible date range changes accordingly.

The problem is, when I have a lot of events (blue squares) visible, and I drag the rows, the UI is very slow. FPS drops dramatically, it's almost unusable. By using the chrome performance tab to analyze this problem, I found that each mousemove event (yellow rectangle in the image below) was taking around 200ms each, so I improved the code and now each mousemove event is taking only 13.38ms (I forgot to put it in the screenshot). But the whole task that includes the mousemove event itself, Recalculate style, Layout, Update layer tree and Paint is taking 56ms, even though way better than 200ms, 56ms is still a lot. The problem is not in the logic, as we can see it only takes 13ms, and Recalculate style, Layout, Update layer tree and Paint are toghether taking around 75% of the time.
[image: Chrome performance analysis tab]
Despite my efforts to improve it, I can't see how I can work around the long time the browser takes to convert the app state into visible content on the screen (purple rectangles in the chrome performance analysis). I have no code to show, since by the analysis I don't think it is a code problem, but a styles problem. My guess is that `position: absolute; left: 123px` properties are slow for the browser to compute, but it is just a guess. And if it is true, I don't know any alternative to it.

Update: Some code that may help:
[image: html code]
[image: blue box css]
[image: component code for left and right properties]
On the get() methods above, the returned values are the correct values that place the events (blue boxes) in the correct place inside its container (just saying).

Comment: it's looks like Angular "recalculate" all the positions. Be sure use **variables** and **not** functions in .html. e.g. if you has `<square style="calculateStyle(event)">` Angular need execute the function always for all squares. if you write `<square style="event.style">` -and when drag you recalculate the property "style" of the event-, Angular not need recalculate all the positions. Without code I can not help you more :(

Comment: I have added some screenshots code that may help

Comment: @eliseo even though I am using a simple method that does not do heavy calculations instead of a using property, is it still very bad for performance? Since it is inside an ngFor, I may have to do some complex logic to replace the method with a property.

Comment: I try to explain me. Angular, when find in HTML some like `[property]="variable"`, each time  the variable change mark it as "dirty". Then, when redraw the app, redraw the elements with properties are "dirty". What happens when Angular find some like  `[property]="function()"`? To know if is "dirty" should execute the function (even if there're no changes) This is the reason to limit use function in html. If you use mousemove, think that your'e making Angular "check if dirty" each mouse move. Try use a `foreach` to add  a new property